# How do I use dual monitors with VMware Player on Windows and an Ubuntu Guest?

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-player

I have my VMware Player (v 3.1.4 build-385536) all up and running Ubuntu (11.04) from my Windows (XP SP2) machine, but now I'm getting greedy and want to run Ubuntu on both monitors.

I've tried manually setting the display options within the VMware Player settings to 2 to no avail. I've also set it to use the host configuration... it doesn't work. What gives?

Answer (score 13):

After you select two screens from the VMware Player settings, there is a little icon that shows up in the pull down title bar thing that says, "Cycle Multiple Monitors" that you need to click to actually enable the multiple monitors. All is wonderful now!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might be able to find it from your computer manufacturer, so for example if you have an HP desktop you could find it from HP's website. Not sure if they will carry an Umbuntu compatible driver or not though, but it be worth checking. If not you should be able to find it at Intel's website. after doing a short search on both google and intels site its seems that there may not be support for your video card on Ubuntu. You may want to consider upgrading your video card, I know Nvidia provides support for Linux, and I am sure ATI does as well. You can get a new card pretty cheap from newegg.

Comment: Before doing anything else you should probably take a look at this video, it's for an older version of Ubuntu, but it should still work. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFX5UssUgcs

Comment: Seems to be more automatic in Version 6, but you still have to do the cycle monitors button.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking you will probably need to install the full version of the drivers for your video card in the Ubuntu VM so that Ubuntu recognizes that you have two monitors hooked up.

Comment: Worked for me on Win7 64bit host and Ubuntu 10.04 guest system. Needed to update vmware tools and reboot guest.

Answer (score 1):

For those running **VMWare** on **Mac**:

**`View`** > **`Use All Displays in Full Screen`**